# Theorem about criteria for being a subbasis for some topology

Tags: general-topology

I was attempting to prove this theorem about subbases. Can I get a validity check, whether I am on the right track? Thanks.

Definition:Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{S}$ a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for $\tau$ if and only if the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of all finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ is a basis for $\tau$.

Proving theorem about subbasis.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and let $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for $\tau$ if and only if

$(1) \mathcal{S} \subset \tau$

$(2)$ for each $U$ in $\tau$ and point $p$ in $U$ there is a finite collection $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ of elements of $\mathcal{S}$ such that $p \in \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} V_i \subset U$.

Proof(attempt):

($\Rightarrow$)
Assume $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for $\tau$. Then each element in $\mathcal{S}$ is in $\tau$, since elements of $\mathcal{S}$ intersected with themselves are basis elements.Each open set $U$ of $\tau$ can be written as a union of elements in $\mathcal{B}$, the set of all finite intersections of elements of $S$. Thus if $U$ is an open set in $\tau$, $U=\bigcup\limits_{B_p \in \mathcal{B}}B_p$. Let $x \in U$. Then $x \in B_p$ for some $p$ and $B_p=S_{1,p} \cap \dots \cap S_{n,p}$ for some $S_{i,p}$ in $\mathcal{S}$. Then $x \in  S_{1,p} \cap \dots \cap S_{n,p}\subset U$ which proves $(2)$.

($\Leftarrow$) Assume $\mathcal{S}$ is a collection of elements satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$.Let $U$ be open in $\tau$. Then for each $p \in U$, there exists $S_{i,p} \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $p \in (S_{1,p} \cap \dots \cap S_{n,p}) \subset U$. Then $U=\bigcup\limits_{p \in U}(S_{1,p} \cap \dots \cap S_{n,p})$. Since each open set is a union of finite intersections of elements in $\mathcal{S}$, $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for $\tau$.

Comment: It seems alright to me.

Comment: The notation is unnecessarily clumsy, but the idea is fine. For the second direction, for instance, I’d use $(2)$ to say that for each $p\in U$,there is a finite $\mathscr{B}_p\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $p\in\bigcap\mathscr{B}_p\subseteq U$ and observe that $U=\bigcup_{p\in U}\bigcap\mathscr{B}_p$, a union of finite intersections of members of $\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: It's just a trivial reformulation of the fact that the finite intersections of subbasic elements form a base. The most common use of subbases is to *define* a topology in the first place, and to apply Alexander's subbase lemma.